# Migrating google app script web app to progressive web app?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I have a working google app script web app and trying to migrate it as a progressive web app. I googled but found no documents on how to do it.
I found a link describing how to migrate a web app into a progressive one in the fallowing link (on the google site):

[Migrate Your Site to Progressive Web App](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/migrate-to-progressive-web-apps/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0)

I started applying the steps but, when it comes to change the default manifest file (appsscript.json) I got an error like **"Invalid manifest:unknown property name**".

The original manifest content was :

```
{
    "timeZone": "Europe/Istanbul",
    "dependencies": {
    },
    "webapp": {
        "access": "MYSELF",
        "executeAs": "USER_DEPLOYING"
    },
    "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER"
}
```

The lines I added were as the above link dictates:

```
"name": "The Most Awesome Dragon Site",
"short_name": "MYFIRSTPWA",
"display": "minimal-ui",
"start_url": "/",
"theme_color": "#673ab6",
"background_color": "#111111",
"icons": [
    {
        "src": "icon-192.png",
        "sizes": "192x192",
        "type": "image/png"
    }
]
```

When i check the info about google manifest file content there were no property names like name, short_name, display, start_url etc. (see the link bellow)

[Manifests](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/manifests)

So does this mean a google app scripts web app can not be migrated to a progressive web app?

İf possible , where to find info on how to?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

These two manifests are very different and perform different functions.

**Apps Script Manifest** - `appsscript.json`

> An Apps Script project manifest is a special JSON file that specifies a basic project information that Apps Script needs to run the script successfully.

This file tells Google infrastructure how it should configure and run your script.

**PWA Manifest** - `manifest.json`

> This manifest file describes meta information about a site, such as how it might look when added to a user's home screen.

This is a JSON file that your HTML links to and user's browsers will download. It's similar to how you would make and serve HTML but it's different content.